# SQL query to fetch the data from the column which has array datatype in postgresql database table

Tags: java, postgresql, jooq

I have created a table with following sql query in database.

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (
   id int PRIMARY KEY,
   name VARCHAR (100),
   contact TEXT []
);
```

Now i populate it with some values.

```
INSERT INTO Employees 
VALUES
   (
      1,
      'Alice John',
      ARRAY [ '132','567' ]
   );
```

**Now my question is how do i write query using java to retrieve
the employee record where contact is '567' ?**

Note: I'm using jooq with postgresql database to perform all query operations.

Comment: Check out the PostgeSQL documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/functions-array.html

Answer (score 0):

jOOQ doesn't support too many vendor specific operations out of the box. In most cases, you are expected to extend jOOQ using [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/). In this case:

```java
ctx.selectFrom(EMPLOYEES)
   .where("{0} @> ARRAY[{1}]", EMPLOYEES.CONTACT, val("567"))
   .fetch();
```